# Is it possible to exclude from being executed a BeanPostProcessor in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a dependency that includes a class implementing `BeanPostProcessor`, and it modifies some beans when application starts.

Is it possible to exclude this class execution, so those beans remain unmodified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using that in your configuration file

```
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = { YourClassName.class }) })
```

This would exclude that  class entirely from becoming a bean.

If you want it later as a bean you must dynamically add it to the context programmatically.

Comment: Would be really helpful if you can explain also how this is working ?